# How to create a timezone/DST accurate date-time plus Unix epoch number?

Tags: python

For a database project, I want a two-field table consisting of the integer portion of a Unix epoch timestamp, and the corresponding human-readable date and time. (I only need 5-minute increments, and I want an integer, so I'm ignoring the decimal portion of the epochal float.)

Being a Python newbie, I am uncertain about the reliability of my methods: my approach currently is to use a time-tuple, which includes the timezone info. But time-tuple appears not to allow addition and subtraction, while datetime objects do. So I thrash around with some conversions. My first attempt:

```
import datetime
import time
sp = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'
otime = datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0)
itime = int(round(time.mktime(otime.timetuple())))
for x in range(0, 50):
    print(str(itime)+ ", " + str(time.strftime(sp, otime.timetuple())))
    otime = otime + datetime.timedelta(seconds=300)
    ttime = time.localtime(time.mktime(otime.timetuple()))
    otime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(ttime))
    itime = int(round(time.mktime(ttime)))
```

This works, and traverses DST time changes correctly for my timezone.

Just incrementing the Unix epoch seconds seems simpler, though:

```
import datetime
import time

sp = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'
otime = datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0)
itime = int(round(time.mktime(otime.timetuple())))
for x in range(0, 50):
    print(str(itime)+ ", " + str(time.strftime(sp, otime.timetuple())))
    itime = itime + 300
    otime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(itime))
```

Both methods seem to give identical output in the ranges I've checked, for example the DST time-change in 2010:

```
1268558100, 03/14/2010 01:15
1268558400, 03/14/2010 01:20
1268558700, 03/14/2010 01:25
1268559000, 03/14/2010 01:30
1268559300, 03/14/2010 01:35
1268559600, 03/14/2010 01:40
1268559900, 03/14/2010 01:45
1268560200, 03/14/2010 01:50
1268560500, 03/14/2010 01:55
1268560800, 03/14/2010 03:00
1268561100, 03/14/2010 03:05
1268561400, 03/14/2010 03:10
1268561700, 03/14/2010 03:15
```

My question: Is there a reason to use datetime.timedelta() instead of simply incrementing the Unix epoch integer by 300 seconds? Will that end up biting me unexpectedly? Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: If your database has a timezone-aware datetime type, you should a single column of that type instead of two potentially inconsistent columns.   The actual answer to your question depends more on what you are planning to do with the datetime values than anything else.  Using unix timestamp values instead of `datetime.timedelta` objects isn't going to bite you by itself, but there are a lot of sharp teeth around when you play with dates & times.